# prove that $g(x) = f(x) \cdot \sin x$ has a minimum in $[0,\infty)$

Tags: limits, functions

$f$ is continuous at $[0,\infty)$

$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=L$, $L \in R$

Let $g(x) = f(x) \cdot \sin x$

1. I had to prove that $g$ is bounded in $[0,\infty)$ which I did.
2. Now It is said that $L=0$ and I need to prove that $g$ gets a minimum in $[0,\infty)$. I know now that $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)=0$ (since $\sin x$ is bounded), $g$ is continuous in $[0,\infty]$. How can I use it to show that $g$ has a minimum?

Comment: In English, we usually say "bounded" instead of "blocked".

Comment: extreme value theorem?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I'm always happy to improve my english here as well

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** It's tricky to come up with the setup, but the proof is easy once you have that.

Suppose that $f(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$. Let $M = |\min \{g(x): x \in [0,1]\}|$.  There exists an $R > 0$ such that $|f(x)| < M$ whenever $x > R$.  Note that $g$ must attain a minimum over the interval $[0,R]$ (why?).  Note that this minimum is necessarily a minimum of $g$ over $[0,\infty)$ (why?).

Comment: 1. $g$ must attain a minimum in that interval since it is continuous in a bounded interval.
2. I can't figure out why that minimum has to be the minimum over $[0,\infty)$. In $(R, \infty)$, $|f(x)| < M$, therefore, $g(x) \le |f(x)| < M$, what other than that can I get?

Comment: See my latest edit.  I think it makes more sense now.

Comment: The idea is that the minimum over $[0,R]$ is at most $-M$, but $g(x) > -M$ for all $x \in (R,\infty)$.

Comment: Sorry I got confused again, it could be that M is negative. therefore, $|f(x)| < M$ makes no sense

Comment: See my latest edit.